# Когда(,) ты хочешь, чтобы я пришёл?

Tags: запятые

Нужны в каких предложениях эти запятые?

1. Где(,) ты хочешь, чтобы мы встретились?
2. Где(,) ты думаешь, он сейчас?
3. Где(,) ты думаешь, что он сейчас находится?
4. Когда(,) ты думаешь, что он к нам придёт-таки?
5. Когда(,) ты хочешь, чтобы я пришёл?

Comment: 3 и 4 безграмотные и неправильные.

Comment: Ху! Это не комметарий – бессмысленность.

Comment: Ну реально. Не по-русски написано. Там стилистика нарушена. Если убрать "что" и "-таки", то правильно.

Comment: Вот, и в ответе убрали, а вы злитесь. "-таки" тоже надо убрать.

Comment: Котяра, опустись! Ты вообще оборзел такое писать? Культуре поведения тебя никто не учил? Хотелось помочь, чтобы всё было грамотно. Тебе надо понять, что неправильное использование слова серьёзнее, чем пропуск запятой. Зачем тебе стилистические ошибки? Можно писать в этом же стиле, но грамотно.

Comment: О господи!.. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZN27lqX12U)

Comment: А я сначала подумала, что это аллегория пожара...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Где ты хочешь, чтобы мы встретились? (Ты хочешь, **чтобы где** мы встретились?)
2. Где, **ты думаешь,** он сейчас?
3. Где, **ты думаешь**, он сейчас находится?   (Нет союза ЧТО)
4. Когда, **ты думаешь**, он к нам придёт-таки? (Нет союза ЧТО)
5. Когда ты хочешь, чтобы я пришёл?  (Ты хочешь, **чтобы когда** я пришёл?)

**Пояснение**

Предложения 1 и 5 **[по правилу Розенталя:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**

Если главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения находится **внутри придаточной** (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только **после главной части** (а перед ней не ставится); ср.: *Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался…* (Г.) — *Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством; Но слова эти мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала…* (Герц.) — *Но мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала эти слова*.

В предложениях 2, 3, 4 "***ты думаешь***" – вводное предложение.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148791/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.